# Multiple Json response to html Table format

Tags: php, mysql, json, html-table, response

I want to fetch data from different servers Database and I need to shown in one Centralised server. So I have written a SELECT query in different locations and I am trying to fetch in one Centralised Server. 
**I am getting a JSON Array response.**

But I tried displaying it in a HTML Table format, but I am unable to get the proper result.

Here is my Centralised server PHP code:

```
 <?php 
    $arr = array (
                    'http://example.com/pristatus/send-curl.php', 
                    'http://example2.com/pristatus/send-curl.php'
                );

                for ($i =0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
                {

                    $ch = curl_init(); 
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $arr[$i]); 
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
                $output = curl_exec($ch); 

            if($output!="error"){
                    $data = json_decode($output);
                }
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($data);
                curl_close($ch); 
                }
    ?>
```

Output I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [status] => OK
            [batch] => 119677
            [location] => Hyderabad
            [createdDT] => 2015-06-19 20:40:05
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [status] => OK
            [batch] => 56339
            [location] => Mumbai
            [createdDT] => 2015-06-19 20:40:05
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [status] => OK
            [batch] => 56339
            [location] => Mumbai
            [createdDT] => 2015-06-19 20:40:05
        )    
)
```

Please suggest me how I can display Json response in a Table format.

Comment: Use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: If it is JSON use `json_decode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use foreach loop and than get value by like

```
foreach($array as $val)

$val->property
```

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($data as $key) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$key->{'id'}.'<td>';
    echo '<td>'.$key->{'status'}.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$key->{'batch'}.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$key->{'location'}.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$key->{'createdDT'}.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thats really Awesome !